# How do I access something from a virtual class so I can use them for If/Else statements in the MAIN class?

Tags: c#, class, virtual

```
class Registration
{
    public virtual void Register()
    {
        int Registration_System;

        Console.Write("Registration System");
        Console.Write("\n 1. Add Student" +
                      "\n 2. View Student" +
                      "\n 3. Search" +
                      "\n 4. Edit" +
                      "\n 5. Delete" +
                      "\n 6. Exit");
        Console.Write("\nChoose: "); Registration_System = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

class Program //Main class
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Registration r = new Registration();
        r.Register();
        MSIT it = new MSIT();
        MSCS cs = new MSCS();



    }
}
```

so basically I need to access **Registration_System**'s value in order to use them in an if/else system for the Main class:

```
if (Registration_System == 1)
{
}
..
```

I'll be doing this with at least 6 other classes since I missed a couple of lessons. So far I just need to set up a skeleton for an If/Else so I can access all the other classes but I can't do that without using **Registration_System**'s value.
Am I doing it correctly though? Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

What about using it as the return value of the Register function, like this:

```
public virtual int Register()
{
    ....
    return Registration_System;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is nothing called as Virtual classes in C#. I guess, you meant Virtual methods (?). Anyway, if you want to access the value of `Registration_System` in your Main class, either you'll have to make it a public global variable in the `Registration` class or will have to encapsulate it in a public property (again in the same `Registration` class) as mentioned by cpl.